# Norm of the upper triangular part of symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, inequalities

Let $D\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ denote a lower triangular matrix. With $\|\cdot\|$ denoting the spectral matrix norm, is there an estimate like

$$
\|D\| \leq C\|D+D^T\|,
$$

where $C>0$ is independent of the dimension $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $D$?

Comment: No. The best constant is $C\sim\ln n$. See this question and the link provided there for background: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177198/norm-of-triangular-truncation-operator-on-rank-deficient-matrices?rq=1

Comment: @ChristianRemling I think you could post this as an answer

Comment: @YemonChoi: OK, will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The best constant is $C_n\sim \ln n$. See, for example, [this paper.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2589115) In particular, for the lower bound, see example 3.3 of the paper.

Comment: Name of this paper: [Bhatia - Pinching, Trimming, Truncating, and Averaging of Matrices](https://doi.org/10.2307/2589115).

Answer (score 4):

The $\log n$ result mentioned by Christian Remling is a special case of the results in

Kwapień, S.; Pełczyński, A. The main triangle projection in matrix spaces and its applications. Studia Math. 34 1970 43–68.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption that $D$ is triangular is not necessary (the Schur decomposition may bring a matrix to its triangular form). If the numerical range of D is contained in a sector, then Lemma 3.1 in http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081087.2014.933219#preview says that there is a C in terms of secant function.

Comment: Unless I have misremembered, even if a square matrix $A$ is unitarily conjugate to a triangular matrix $D$, it might not be the case that $A+A^\top$ is unitarily conjugate to $D+D^\top$. Therefore I think that the question as stated really does want to start with the assumption that $D$ is triangular.

Comment: @Yemon, Yes, you are right. If the transpose $^T$ is replaced with the conjugate transpose $^*$, then my comment is valid.

Comment: Name of the linked paper:  [Zhang - A matrix decomposition and its applications](https://doi.org/10.1080/03081087.2014.933219).