# Operator norm of triangular truncation on symmetric matrices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices, inequalities

Inspired by [this question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177944/norm-of-the-upper-triangular-part-of-symmetric-matrix)

It is known that for the matrix $T_n \in \mathcal{M}_n$ (the space of real-valued $n \times n$ matrices) defined by
\begin{equation*}
(T_n)_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1 & i \geq j \\
0 & i < j
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

and arbitrary $A \in \mathcal{M}_n$, that $\|T_n \circ A\| \leq \frac{\ln n}{\pi}\|A\|$, where $\circ$ represents Hadamard/Schur multiplication and $\|\cdot\|$ represents the spectral norm.

My question is this:

> Let $B \in \mathcal{M}_n$ be symmetric. Is the above inequality still best possible, or can it be improved? To be more exact, is there a sequence of symmetric $n \times n$ matrices $B_n$ such that $\|T_n \circ B_n\| \approx   \|B_n\|\ln n$ ?

Try as I might, I can find no results in the literature about this (though I can find many about the norm of Hadamard multiplication with $T_n$ acting on $\mathcal{M}_n$) and I cannot seem to come up with an example of a suitable $\{B_n\}$ myself.

Any help would be much appreciated, even if it is to recommend a resource or reference. Thanks so much!

Comment: Since you say symmetric, I am guessing that your matrices are real-valued rather than complex-valued?

Comment: Yes, they are! I shall amend the original post for clarification.

Comment: This is answered in the question you linked to: the best constant is still $\sim\log n$. (What you call $T\circ B$ corresponds to $D$ there, and of course $D+D^t$ is symmetric and can be your $B$.)

Comment: I don't see how it's answered; I checked through all the references and the counterexample that was used to show that the constant is of $\log n$ is anti-symmetric, not symmetric. I'm curious if anyone has any reason to believe that symmetric matrices still have this extremal behaviour, because I can't find anything in that question that says so.

Comment: If I'm being silly and there's a clear example of a sequence of symmetric matrices that display this property (i.e. have a constant in terms of $\log n$) please let me know!

Comment: @ChristianRemling. Your comment is not correct. Because the diagonal of $D$ may be nonzero, $D$ differs from $T\circ B$ where $B:=D+D^T$.

Comment: @DenisSerre Removing the diagonal of $D$ does not affect much the norm of $D$ and $B$. Anyway, the answers to the question given by the OP contains the answer verbatim. Actually, the standard example of matrices proving that the triangular projection has norm $\sim \log n$ is (some kind of) Hilbert matrix, and is symmetric. See for example Proposition 1.2 in the paper by Kwapien and Pelcczynksi that is provided in Bill Johnson's answer.

Comment: This is untrue; the triangular cut used in Kwapien and Pelczynski is for everything below the main cross-diagonal, not the main diagonal of the matrix. Their result doesn't apply here, unfortunately, as you would have to "rotate" the matrix somewhat and in doing that you would get an anti-symmetric matrix.

Comment: @DenisSerre: That is certainly not a problem: if we normalize such that$\|D+D^t\|=1$, then the diagonal has operator norm $\le 1$ and can be removed from $D$ if desired without changing the ratio between $\|D\|$ and $\|D+D^t\|$ much.

Comment: I remember trying symmetric random matrices with Gaussian N(0,1) entries; for these the upper triangular based truncation had $\frac{1}{\pi}\log n$ type of bound....cannot locate my notes about that right now; at least empirically this can be checked and perhaps proved subsequently directly.

Comment: @SAWblade You are right, I read Kwapien-Pelczynski too fast. But using that $iA$ is hermitian when $A$ is skew-symmetric, you can pass from skew-symmetric to symmetric and conversely. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be accepting that the norm of the triangular projection restrited to skew-symmetric matrices is of order $\log n$. There is an easy trick to deduce that the same is true on symmetric matrices. Operator algebraists like it a lot and call it *the $2$-by-$2$ matrix trick*.

The trick is: if $A \in M_n$ is skew-symmetric, then $A'=A\otimes J =A \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is symmetric. If you choose the correct identification between $M_n \otimes M_2$ and $M_{2n}$, then the triangular projection of $A'$ is almost $(T_n \circ A)\otimes J$ (it is exactly $(T_n \circ A)\otimes J - (I_n \circ A) \otimes \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$). This implies that $$\|T_{2n}\circ A'\| \geq \|T_n \circ A\| - \|A\|,$$
and that the norm of $T_{2n}$ restricted to symmetric matrices is larger that (the norm of $T_n$ restricted to skew-symmetric matrices) minus $1$, QED.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "the correct identification between $M_n \otimes M_2$ and $M_{2n}$"?

Comment: I ask because I cannot see how $T_{2n} \circ A' = (T_n \circ A) \otimes J - (I_n \circ A) \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @SAWblade Order the elements of $\{1,\dots,n\} \times\{1,2\}$ as follows: $(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),\dots,(n,1),(n,2)$.

Comment: ... in that way, if $0\leq i,j\leq n-1$ and $1\leq \alpha,\beta\leq 2$, the entry $(2i+\alpha,2j+\beta)$ of $A'$ is $A_{i+1,j+1}J_{\alpha,\beta}$.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect as $I_n \circ A$ would be the zero matrix, and also $(T_n \circ A)\otimes J - A \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is equal to the symmetric matrix $B$ where the upper right corner is $T_n \circ A$, not $T_{2n} \circ A'$.